# Latex \in and \Z both cause Undefined Control Sequence error

Tags: math-mode, symbols

My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
...
Ex. If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is even.
Proof: Let $y$ \in \Z $: x = 2y$ (we know y exists from the definition of even). Then:
\begin{equation} 
    x^2 = (2y)^2
    x^2 = 4y^2
    x^2 = 2(2y^2)
    (2y^2) is an Integer (because Integers are closed under multiplication), so x^2 is Even.
\end{equation}
```

But when I run `pdflatex file.tex`, I get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.26 Proof: Let $y$ \in 
                            \Z $: x = 2y$ (we know y exists from the defini...

?
```

I tried putting the `\in \Z` in the `$...$` section, and tried changing `$...$` to `\(...\)`, to no avail. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

(To explain: I got the symbols from [this list](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols). It seems the list is not entirely accurate)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It looks like you haven't defined the macro `\Z`; I assume it should be defined as `\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}`. Also, instead of `$y$ \in \Z $: x = 2y$`, write `$y \in \Z : x = 2y$` -- get rid of two of the `$` symbols.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\in` is a math mode symbol, which requires math mode.

`\Z` is just undefined. My guess is something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathds{Z}}

\begin{document}
Ex. If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is even.
Proof: Let $y \in \Z\colon x = 2y$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \mathds]

Or using `\mathbb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\newcommand*{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}
Ex. If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is even.
Proof: Let $y \in \Z\colon x = 2y$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \mathbb]

Also environment `equation` is not intended for more than one equation. See documentation of package `amsmath`. It provides many environments (`align`, `gather`, ...) for equation systems.

Comment: Thank you! I'm confused though: the symbols were listed [here](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols) - the link is wrong?

Comment: @Miryafa - The table you've linked to is dodgy. For sure, neither the LaTeX kernel nor the `amssymb` package define `\N`, `\Z`, `\Q`, `\R`, etc.

Comment: @Miryafa See: [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: curious why you bothered to load `amssymb` when you override it with `dsfont`.  `\in` is one of the "core" math symbols, so no extra package is needed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The start of the preamble is just inherited from the question. Also packages `mathtools`, `geometry`, and the settings of `\parindent` and `\parskip` are not needed for the example. The preamble additions for defining `\Z` are separated by a blank line.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you wanted?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
...
Ex. If $x$ is even, then $x^2$ is even.
Proof: Let $y\in Z : x = 2y$ (we know y exists from the definition of even). Then:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
    x^2 &= (2y)^2\\
   \Leftrightarrow x^2 &= 4y^2\\
   \Leftrightarrow x^2 &= 2(2y^2)
   \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
    $(2y^2)$ is an Integer (because Integers are closed under multiplication), so $x^2$ is Even.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks good too! Thank you (I upvoted your answer, but don't yet have enough rep for it to show).